# Entity Framework does not add value to one column

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to export data from JSON file to SQL database using Entity Framework. I am doing it like this:

```
// If database is empty, seed data        
if (!_context.Classes.Any())
{
    var classes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class>>(await File.ReadAllTextAsync("PATH\\data.json"));

    foreach (var @class in classes)
    {
        await _classRepository.AddClass(@class);
        await _classRepository.SaveChanges();
    }

    var updatedPupils = new List<Pupil>();

    foreach (var @class in classes)
    {
        foreach (var pupil in @class.Pupils)
        {
            var copy = pupil;
            copy.GradutaionYear = @class.GraduationYear;
            updatedPupils.Add(copy);
        }
   }

   foreach (var pupil in updatedPupils)
   {
       await _pupilRepository.AddPupil(pupil);
       await _pupilRepository.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

In this method I am updating *pupil* field called `GraduationYear` by copying the value from class entity from filed called `GraduationYear`. But after this operation, the `GraduationYear` field has not been updated in the database, it remains null.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhGJr.png)

How can I fix it?

*edit*

After check in debugger, one thing I am sure, entities in `updatedPupils` list have correct value in `GraduationYear` field.

Classes code

```
public class Class
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string ClassProfile { get; set; }
    public string GraduationYear { get; set; }
    public string ClassPhoto { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Pupil
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string GradutaionYear { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Class Class { get; set; }
}
```

*edit 2*

```
public async Task<Pupil> AddPupil(Pupil entity)
{
    var result = await _context.Pupils.AddAsync(entity);
    return result.Entity;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what is in `@class.GraduationYear`? That way you can see if it goes wrong in parsing your JSON, or in inserting to your database.

Comment: `@class.GraduationYear` has correct value.

Comment: could you post the code for your class?

Comment: @KenTucker added

Comment: `var copy = pupil;` does not copy the entry. Try it with a `new pupil` object and copy all the properties.

Comment: As soon as you deserialize the data, update the `GraduationYear` field like this: `foreach (var pupil in @class.Pupils) {  pupil.GradutaionYear = @class.GraduationYear;)`. Then add all your classes to the repository within a loop but do not call `SaveChanges`. Call `SaveChanges` only once at the end. This will save the `Class` and the `Pupil` collection for that class. You do not need to add the Pupils and save them separately. (But I do not know how you have implemented your repositories).

Comment: Also while you are at it, fix the spelling mistake in `Pupil.GradutaionYear` because it will give you more headaches later on. Why is `GraduationYear` a `string`, should it not be a number?

Comment: @CodingYoshi I am using string because this field is only used to display as description. I updated post to repository code.

Comment: Did you try what I mentioned above?

Comment: @CodingYoshi yes, your tips worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look to this code :

```
var copy = pupil;
copy.GradutaionYear = @class.GraduationYear;
updatedPupils.Add(copy);
```

In c#, the symbol equal `=` copy a variable but keep a reference to origin variable, so when you do `copy.GradutaionYear = @class.GraduationYear` you update both `GradutaionYear` properties of `copy` and `pupil` vars.

So, this code `var copy = pupil; copy.GradutaionYear = @class.GraduationYear;` is the same as doing `pupil.GradutaionYear = @class.GraduationYear`.

Second, do a `SaveChange()` in a loop, it's a very very very bad idea and can be very heavy, very long, and can throw stack OverFlow exception. You could use that in specific case if you don't have any others choices, but you must be sure of what you are doing.

Thridly, `SaveChange()` will save entities and children entities too. So adding `classes` will also add children pupils to database.

By knowing all of that, you can simplify your code to :

```
foreach (var @class in classes)
{
    foreach (var pupil in @class.Pupils)
        pupil.GradutaionYear = @class.GraduationYear;
    await _classRepository.AddClass(@class);
}
await _classRepository.SaveChanges();
```

This should work, tell me if you have any trouble

Comment: At first, I know about references, I tried this code because I was desperated. I tried your solution, but result is same. `GraduationYear` still remains null. But thank you for tip with `SaveChanges` method.

Comment: @ggo you do not need to add pupils because when a class is added, its children (pupils) will also be added to the context. Also, you only need one save.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. When I was only adding `classes`, it also added `pupils` to database. Solution is simple. Update `pupils` before adding them to database.

```
foreach (var @class in classes)
{
    foreach (var pupil in @class.Pupils)
    {
        pupil.GradutaionYear = @class.GraduationYear;
    }

    await _classRepository.AddClass(@class);
}

await _classRepository.SaveChanges();
```